# 4 months into position found out my salary is below the minimum for position, how should I handle this?

Tags: management, salary

I've been with with a large bank for 4 years, same line of work 3 years, my new position 4 months and I saw a posting for my same position showing the minimum salary about $2000 higher than mine. My past years evaluations have been above average and I am doing well in my new department. I want to discuss this with my manager, but don't want to sound greedy. Any tips or advice on how I should handle this?

Comment: "don't want to sound greedy" - well obviously your pay has been adequate for your living circumstances. So if you don't want to sound greedy don't ask for a pay rise. However, your employers haven't been as worried about being greedy over the past 4 years...

Answer (score 3):

As Bruce Hornsby said, that's just the way it is.

You've moved into the new role internally, hr have possibly moved you to the top end of salary for your grade, or maybe moved you up a grade (I'm assuming the new role paid some more).

What that has to do with what they would need to pay someone on the open market to come in, frankly nothing.  They will offer what they need to compete with other companies vying for candidates.

What can you do, you can ask, but unless you have a unique selling point, it is unlikely to do much.

I've had my people in my teams hit this before, different rules apply I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means that the salary was lower when you started, and the market rate has increased faster than your wages. Basically, they don't feel they would be able to hire someone for your salary.

The best you can do is approach it with your manager.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is usually to ask your manager what you'd need to do in order to get a raise to that level. It's sometimes already in progress, or you may just need to given him/her  a bit more ammunition to take forward when the year-end evaluations are done.

If you aren't given some productive route to achieve that, you have only two choices. One is to decide that it isn't worth worrying about (you're being paid "enough" or you wouldn't have taken the job). Or you can decide that it's something you're willing to quit over... because trying to insist on a raise that they aren't ready to give you is likely to result in your being offered that alternative .., and start a job hunt to find out whether you really can get the additional money.

I much prefer to try to work with my employer rather than playing power games against them, not least because they have most of the power. But others feel otherwise. Your mileage will vary.